# Как запретить изменение размера ниже определенного?

Tags: python, tkinter

Допустим окно 500x500 пикселей, мне надо запретить изменять размер этого окна меньше 300x300, как такое реализовать?
Поначалу думал как то считывать размер окна и если оно меньше определённого запрещать его изменять, но в таком случае его нельзя будет вернуть обратно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым же [результатом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448882/how-do-i-set-the-initial-window-size-as-the-minimum-window-size-in-tkinter) (в старой версии название чуть другое `minsize()`) из гугла, в модуле `tkinter` есть функция `wm_minsize()`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.wm_minsize(height, width) 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте к примеру это, только под себя поставьте данные

```
b1 = Label(text="Label", width=20, height=3)
if  b1.width =< 300 and height =< 300:
    raise Valueerror('минимальный размер окна 300x300)
```

Comment: Это не будет работать, как минимум из-за того что у вас проверка только при запуске программы. При попытке изменить размер окна никаких проверок не будет.

Comment: тоже верно сенкс